# FailedPredicateException handling to jump to the next alternative

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have some ambiguous input. What I want to do is to skip one of the alternatives if my predicate evaluates to false inside of the rule(I want to check if my chain hasn't a whitespace inside, but don't want to actually produce Whitespace tokens and inject it to every rule).
I know I can catch exceptions with antlr, but it seems only for a global rule scope.
I guess I can try something with java code instead.
For example, I have some java code which antlr4 produces:

```java
            switch ( getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,117,_ctx) ) {
            ...
            case 4:
                {
                _localctx = new ChainExpressionContext(_localctx);
                _ctx = _localctx;
                _prevctx = _localctx;
                setState(907);
                chain();
                }
                break;
            ...
            case 34:
                {
                _localctx = new FunctionExpressionContext(_localctx);
                _ctx = _localctx;
                _prevctx = _localctx;
                setState(953);
                functionCallNoParen();
                }
                break;
            }
```

What I want to do is something like this

```java
boolean flag = true;
int _myalt = getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,117,_ctx);
while (flag) {
            flag = false;
            switch ( _myalt ) {
            ...
            case 4:
                {
                _localctx = new ChainExpressionContext(_localctx);
                _ctx = _localctx;
                _prevctx = _localctx;
                setState(907);
                try {
                    chain();
                } catch (FailedPredicateException) {
                   if (**Also adaptivePredict of this rule reported ambiguity**) {
                       flag = true;
                       _myalt = 34;
                       continue;
                    }
                }
                break;
            ...
            }
}
```

Is it possible even(I mean may code like this break the whole antlr parsing somehow)? Or antlr have some better approaches for this like custom error handling?

## EDIT

For example I have grammar

```
chain
    : chainBase memberAccess*
    ;

expression
    : ...                                  
    | chain                                                                  
    ...
    | functionCallNoParen                                                   
    ;
```

I would like to parse ambiguous phrases(For a parser with one channel, where HIDDEN tokens are ignored by default this input looks just identical)

```
put (123).abc
put(123).abc
```

differently depending on a whitespace characters inside(first is functionCallNoParen, second is chain), so I can try something like

```
chain
    : chainBase {!isCurrentTokenAWhitespace()}? memberAccess*
    ;
```

and here comes the described problem

Comment: This should be enough

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue in my MySQL grammar, where a whitespace decides if I have to deal with a keyword followed by an open parenthesis or see a function call. For that I have a predicate that turns a keyword into a normal identifier, depending on the existance of one or more whitespaces (which is ultimately controlled by an SQL mode). In your case you could do that with your `put` keyword. Here's an example:

```
ADDDATE_SYMBOL: A D D D A T E { setType(determineFunction(ADDDATE_SYMBOL)); }; // MYSQL-FUNC
```

The single letter rules are just there to allow case independent keywords (e.g. `A: 'A' | 'a';`). You can see the full grammar here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLLexer.g4.

The function `setType` comes from the ANTLR4 runtime (here the lexer instance) and `determineFunction` is a member function in my custom lexer class that is defined as:

```
size_t MySQLBaseLexer::determineFunction(size_t proposed) {
  // Skip any whitespace character if the sql mode says they should be ignored,
  // before actually trying to match the open parenthesis.
  if (isSqlModeActive(IgnoreSpace)) {
    size_t input = _input->LA(1);
    while (input == ' ' || input == '\t' || input == '\r' || input == '\n') {
      getInterpreter<atn::LexerATNSimulator>()->consume(_input);
      channel = HIDDEN;
      type = MySQLLexer::WHITESPACE;
      input = _input->LA(1);
    }
  }

  return _input->LA(1) == '(' ? proposed : MySQLLexer::IDENTIFIER;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `put` is not a keyword, just any identifier. I can actually try your approach with skipping whitespace inside lexer, but I don't understand how to link your `IgnoreSpace` with a parser, or is it even came from parser.

Comment: You can of course use the approach in any parser or lexer rule and do your validation in native code (looking back or forward in the input stream). That `IgnoreSpace` flag is a member in my lexer class which is set based on the current SQL mode. That's not really relevant for you and I left it in only to show that you can make your decision based on some external condition, if necessary (e.g. to toggle certain language features based on some flags or the language version).

Comment: The problem is I can't determine where I should ignore whitespace exactly, I would like to make antlr choose the correct alternative based on whitespace presence. I described it [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2609). So I'm trying to overcome it somehow. Did you have such problems in your antlr4 expirience?